# How to -graphically- know branches' parents?

Tags: git, branch

Many times I've researched this and many times I've got frustrated.

Wrapping up the answers I've found: "Branches are simply pointers to commits, so it is not possible to see where a branch originated from", and neither, I suppose, to get a graphical representation of branches in a repository.

Is that true? Is it really impossible to get a clear tree representation of the branches?
Something like this:

[image]

Thank you.